# In order to make a table(containing datepicker) responsive, the format of the calendar changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, html-table

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',  beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
        }, 0);
    }}).val();
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
        }, 0);
    }}).val();

});

function getBookingDates() {

var Checkin = $('#datepicker1').val();
var Checkout = $('#datepicker2').val();

var promo = $("#PromoCode").text();
var noofadults = $( "#adults option:selected" ).text();
var noofchildren = $( "#children option:selected" ).text();
  
var booking1 = "https://www.thebookingbutton.com.au/properties/qbatcoldirect?check_in_date=";
var booking2 = "&check_out_date=";
var booking3 = "¤cy=AUD&number_adults=";
var booking4 = "&number_children=";

return booking1 + Checkin + booking2 + Checkout + booking3 + noofadults + booking4 + noofchildren;
}

function thelink() {
    var redirectURL = getBookingDates();
   window.location.assign(redirectURL);
 }

</script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
```

```css
<style>
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
   table { 
   width: 100%; 
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
 }
 td { 
   padding: 6px; 
   /*border: 1px solid #ccc;  */
   text-align: left; 
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
 (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
  table, td, tr { 
  display: block; 
 }
 tr {/* border: 1px solid #ccc;*/ }
 td { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;  */
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%; 
 }
 td:before { 
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
  </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hotel Bookings</title>

<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

  
  <body> 

<form>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                 <td class="lbl"><label for="datepicker1">Checkin</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="datepicker1" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"></td>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="datepicker2">Checkout</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="datepicker2" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"></td>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="adults">Adults</label></td>
                    <td><select name="adults" id="adults">
           <option>1</option>
           <option selected="selected">2</option>
           <option>3</option>
           <option>4</option>
           <option>5</option>
           <option>6</option>
           <option>7</option>
           <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
           <option>10</option>
           </select></td>
                    <td class="lbl"><label for="children">Children</label></td>
                    <td><select name="children" id="children">
           <option selected="selected">0</option>
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
           <option>3</option>
           <option>4</option>
           <option>5</option>
           <option>6</option>
           <option>7</option>
           <option>8</option>
           <option>9</option>
           <option>10</option>
         </select></td>
                    <td class="lbl"><input type="button" value="Check Availability" onClick="thelink()"></td>
  
   </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
```

I have made the table responsive successfully but the calendar - datepicker appears vertically meaning all the date appear one below the other which is not feasible. How can I make the table responsive without changing the appearance of datepicker?

Comment: The _best_ solution is: **don't** use a _table_ for layout.  Tables aren't meant to do layout. Maybe look into a _flex_ layout.

Comment: @StephenP: Have never used that before, will check that though. Wanted to know if the problem can be solved with the existing code.